# Using captcha with couchdb for antispam

Tags: couchdb, captcha

Is there a way to implement captcha on a couchdb app?

I am writing a signup page on my application and I want to have protection against spam signups. It seems that I would have to do that with a server alongside couchdb. I was hoping to avoid that. 
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could add documents to CouchDB in a "pending" state and then use a changes listener to update them to an "approved" state.

You could even stick that code in a design document and use the changes consumer I wrote in node http://www.mikealrogers.com/archives/726